# How to look up values in a large JSON file in Dart

Tags: json, list, dictionary, dart, flutter

I have a large JSON file with many objects with many properties. Simplified structure looks like this:

```
"allGadgets": [
      {
        "Model Code": "nokia1",
        "Top Category": "Mobile Phones",
        "Category": "non-iPhone",
        "Brand": "Nokia",
        "Device": "1",

        "Price": "£ 11"
      },
      {
        "Model Code": "nokia2",
        "Top Category": "Mobile Phones",
        "Category": "non-iPhone",
        "Brand": "Nokia",
        "Device": "2",

        "Price": "£ 17",
      },
      {
        "Model Code": "nokia3",
        "Top Category": "Mobile Phones",
        "Category": "non-iPhone",
        "Brand": "Nokia",
        "Device": "3",

        "Price": "£ 10",

      }] ... plus a few hundreds more of different brands and models
```

I'm extracting from this json list of maps a list of Strings for a search panel for the user to look up their device. The Strings are made of two of the values from the json, i.e.: `"${item['Brand']} - ${item['Device']}"`

Once the user has selected the relevant model from the dropdown search panel, I need to use this string value to give them the price from the json file. The question is how do I achieve that in dart/flutter? If it was html/css, I would have added an extra hidden field of model code and/or price itself and then just made it visible.

In flutter/dart, however, a search panel plugin I found only accepts Strings, which the user selects and which then have to be used to look up the the corresponding price value in the json file.

Complicating the lookup is the fact that my Strings are now composed of two field values with spaces and a hyphen in between so I probably need to convert them back into how they had been prior to the string conversion and then use both for the lookup... which sounds quite convoluted...

Any thoughts on how to solve the above task would be welcome!

What I guess would help a lot is an example - looking up an object using a String (formed from two values from the objects) within a json with many objects. User is presented with a subset of those objects, but just sees a couple of fields from them. Then the user effectively selects a query using the String shown to him based off the two fields. That String then allows to look up the object and find another value (price) in that corresponding object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having decoded your json, you have a `List` of `Map`s. Make a new data structure which is a `Map` of `Map`s (i.e. `Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>`). Populate the new `Map` by adding each member of the `List`, keyed by the brand/device name. Now you can directly look up the device details by that composite name.

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> original;
Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> data = {};

original.forEach((item) {
  String brandDeviceName = '${item['Brand']} - ${item['Device']}';
  data[brandDeviceName] = item;
});
```

Comment: That's a clever way around it! My only concern is we are creating another map of an already large map... Do you think that's the most efficient way? I like it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that you aren't copying the data - you're just adding an additional reference to it. It'll work fine.

Comment: If that's useful, don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: @RichardHeap My question is similar to this one, can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507988/optimal-parsing-of-large-json-in-background